# What does the algorithm "NLOPT_LD_auglag" do?

Tags: r, algorithm, nlopt

I have encountered some code which uses the algorithms NLOPT_LD_MMA and NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG.

I can't find any documentation, in particular on NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG.

I want to know what the algorithms are doing, as I want to execute the task with some additional constraints.

```
opts <- list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG",
             "xtol_rel"=1.0e-8, "maxeval" = 500, 
             "local_ops" = list("algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_MMA",
                                "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-8))
```

Unfortunately I am unable to provide you with the rest of my code, I am really looking for an explanation of what is going on under the hood of these algorithms (preferably with some maths if possible!)

Comment: `LD`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/vignettes/nloptr.pdf - last chapter of page 2 ( local minima (L) using a derivative-based (D) algorithm). `Auglag`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method
Someone correct me if my interpretation is wrong :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot about `MMA`, it refers to Svanberg in the nloptr vignette, which leads to this handy link: https://people.kth.se/~krille/mmagcmma.pdf. Stands for "method of moving asymptotes"